# Applying my Compiz settings to other user

Tags: 10.10, configuration, compiz

Where are all the Compiz settings stored? I would like to have another user have Compiz configured the exact same way, what is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While copying your gconf files should work, you could also use the compizconfig settings manager, and and export your profile.

The other user can import this the same way.

Comment: this is the preferred method, but sometimes it doesn't work when using the gconf config backend.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is just as simple as copying .gconf/apps/compiz from your home dir to him.